# I'm trying to run a pipeline using python slaves on Jenkins but somehow it's always shows this output : jenkins doesn't have label 'python'

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, openshift

So, i'm running the jenkins image on openshift 3.11 server and i'm trying to run a pipeline on Jenkins but somehow i can't use jenkins python slave, it's always shows this command when i'm trying to build the pipeline : jenkins doesn't have label 'python'

The thing is if i'm changed the label to 'master' it works but doesn't produce the output that i'm expected.

This is the kubernetes pod & container template config :
Name : python 
Labels: python 
Container Template: 
Name: jnlp 
Docker Image: idealo/jenkins-slave-python-centos7:latest 
Always pull image: True 
Working directory: /tmp 
Arguments to pass to the command: ${computer.jnlpmac}${computer.name}

Also the only active node in Jenkins nodes was master node and nothing else. P.S. the git repository was a private repository.

```
#This is the jenkinsfile for the pipeline

pipeline {
    agent {
          node {
              label 'python' 
          }
    }
    environment {
        APPLICATION_NAME = 'abc'
        GIT_REPO="https://gitlab.playcourt.id/user/abc.git"
        GIT_BRANCH="master"
        STAGE_TAG = "promoteToQA"
        DEV_PROJECT = "test-cicd"
        STAGE_PROJECT = "myproject"
        TEMPLATE_NAME = "abc"
        ARTIFACT_FOLDER = "target"
        PORT = 8080;
        passwd = 123;
    }
    stages {
         stage('Get Latest Code') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'abc', passwordVariable: 'user', usernameVariable: 'user')]) {
                        sh('git pull https://${user}:${user}@gitlab.playcourt.id/user/abc.git')
                    }
            }
        }

#etc..
```

It always shows an output "Jenkins doesn't have label 'python'"
Any help or feedback would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Also the only active node in Jenkins nodes was master node and nothing else.

You need to have an active agent or slave with the label "python".
This will work if you update, for example, your existing `master` node and add python label to it or you **add a new slave** with label python.

> The thing is if i'm changed the label to 'master' it works but doesn't produce the output that i'm expected.

If this is the case, maybe there is something wrong with a different part of your pipeline. If you post more details on how the output is different from your expectation, then maybe I can help you with it.

Comment: @suisense Thanks for the feedback, probably i'm missing some detail here cause i'm new on this pipeline thing, so i'm trying to run the pipeline using python slaves that provided by kubernetes pod template but it seems that jenkins doesn't detect it. I found this article https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/using_images/other_images/jenkins_slaves.html that quite help if somehow my slaves configurations were false but i'm not quite sure on how to run the python slaves from the jenkins master.

Comment: Maybe try to run a test job first on your pod slave (not a pipeline) and check if that works. I'm not familiar with openshift but I found this article that was, upon skimming, quite easy to follow: https://medium.com/@diegolovison/how-to-deploy-a-jenkins-slave-in-openshift-to-connect-with-a-remote-jenkins-master-41d51e5eb9f6 You can check it out and if I have time later, I will try it as well.